# GWT rpc failing - base url not what I expected

Tags: gwt, resources, rpc

I am trying to become familiar with using the GWT api to create web based applications. I have been following some tutorials on GWT and have not yet been able to make an RPC call. Looking at the problem with a broad scope, my goals are to make a server call to run a series of database tests that I know work (ive tested this code).

---EDIT---

I think that the problem here is that the resource is being looked for here:
/MatesWeb/org.matesweb.Main/peopleService

when I think it should be looked for here:
/MatesWeb/peopleService

---END_EDIT---

Here is the info and code I feel is relevant:

-using netbeans

-error that I am getting is "/MatesWeb/org.matesweb.Main/PeopleService - description - The requested resource is not available."

-GWT.getModuleBaseURL() returns: :8080/MatesWeb/org.matesweb.Main/

-URL in browser is: :8080/MatesWeb/

from web.xml file

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>peopleService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.matesweb.server.PeopleServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>peopleService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/peopleService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

From PeopleService Service
    package org.matesweb.client;

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("PeopleService")
public interface PeopleService extends RemoteService {

String[] saveGetPerson(String[] persInfo);
int runTests();

}
```

From PeopleServiceImpl
    package org.matesweb.server;

```
import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;
import org.matesweb.client.PeopleService;

import org.matesweb.server.tests.DbTest;

class PeopleServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements PeopleService {

    @Override
    public String[] saveGetPerson(String[] persInfo) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public int runTests()
    {
        int retInt;

        DbTest dbTest = new DbTest();
        retInt = dbTest.runTests();
        return retInt;
    }

}
```

From PeopleServiceAsync

```
package org.matesweb.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;

public interface PeopleServiceAsync
{
  void saveGetPerson(String[] persInfo, AsyncCallback<String[]> persInformation);
  void runTests(AsyncCallback<Integer> retInt);
}
```

Any idea of whats going on here?

Cheers,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("PeopleService")
```

The `@RemoteServiceRelativePath` annotation is used to decide what url to hit. This *path* to the server is *relative* to the compiled module itself - the gwt app loaded from the path `/MatesWeb/org.matesweb.Main/`, so the service is being sought out at `/MatesWeb/org.matesweb.Main/PeopleService`. I assume this means you have an html file in the `MatesWeb/` directory (probably the .war file is called MatesWeb?), and inside of there exists the compiled app in `org.matesweb.Main/`, including the initial JS file, `org.matesweb.Main.nocache.js`.

If you want to tell the service to be found at `/MatesWeb/peopleService`, you have two options. The first is to modify the annotation to back up a directory, something like this:

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("../peopleService")
```

Using `..`, I indicate the parent directory, and I also changed the case of the path part 'peopleService' - this may or may not matter. A second option is to set the url programmatically:

```
PeopleServiceAsync service = GWT.create(PeopleService.class);
((ServiceDefTarget)service).setServiceEntryPoint("/MatesWeb/peopleService");
```

As referenced in the `@RemoteServiceRelativePath` javadocs http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/RemoteServiceRelativePath.html.

If, instead, you want to leave the client as is and tell the server that this service should be at the path the client expects, you can modify the `web.xml` to make the servlet available at the path that the client is currently expecting to find it:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>peopleService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MatesWeb/org.matesweb.Main/PeopleService</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Note again that I've changed the case - it may not matter, but I generally like to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

First hunch is PeopleService must be peopleService in the @RemoteServiceRelativePath . Please use firebug to monitor your rpc requests. You can observe and verify request url issues like these easily.

Update your URL pattern in web.xml as in here

```
<url-pattern>/org.matesweb.Main/greet</url-pattern>
```

Comment: I tried changing that and it didnt seem to help at all. I think that the problem here is that the resource is being looked for here:
/MatesWeb/org.matesweb.Main/peopleService

when I think it should be looked for here:
/MatesWeb/peopleService